# Facebook Login Custom Designed Button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-login

Is it possible to use the the facebook login plugin with a custom UI button on my side? I dont want to use the standard FB plugin that comes with the plugin.

I want to be able to click a custom button and have it do the same action, launch pop/modal to sync.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can!  But you'll have to do some JavaScript coding for it.   If you use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you'll be able to log your users into your website using any element that you can trigger a JavaScript function with.

Check out the [FB.login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) function :

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log('Logged out.');
       });
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

This function will initiate a login popup for users that have not yet logged in and request their email addresses.

It's more work than just pasting the plugin, but if you want to customize the login features then this is the way you will accomplish it.

Comment: Ok great thanks for the quick response! Do you know if there are <no script> fallbacks for FB plugins inside of the iframes if there was no JS enable for accessibility concerns?

Comment: There is no way even with the facebook plugin as it requires javascript to run.  I don't even think the facebook website itself would work with javascript turned off.